# Change the onClick function to target the edit buttons

Tags: javascript

I have the following script

```
var counter = 0;
function appendText(){

        var text = document.getElementById('usertext').value;

            if ( document.getElementById('usertext').value ){

                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.className = 'divex';

                var li = document.createElement('li');
                li.setAttribute('id', 'list');  
                div.appendChild(li);

                var texty = document.createTextNode(text);
                var bigdiv = document.getElementById('addedText');

                var editbutton = document.createElement('BUTTON');
                editbutton.setAttribute('id', 'button_click');
                var buttontext = document.createTextNode('Edit');
                editbutton.appendChild(buttontext); 

                bigdiv.appendChild(li).appendChild(texty);
                bigdiv.appendChild(li).appendChild(editbutton);

                document.getElementById('button_click').setAttribute('onClick', makeAreaEditable());

                document.getElementById('usertext').value = "";
                counter++;
        }        
};                                                          

var makeAreaEditable = function(){    

    alert('Hello world!');
};
```

I want the makeAreaeditable function to work when the Edit button is pressed(for each of the edit buttons that are appended under the textarea).. In this state, the script, alerts me when i hit the Addtext button.

the following is the html. P.S. i need this in pure javascript, if you can help. thanks

```
    <textarea id="usertext"></textarea>
    <button onClick="appendText()">Add text </button>


    <div id="addedText" style="float:left">
    </div>
```

Comment: `setAttribute('onClick', makeAreaEditable());` will **execute** the `makeAreaEditable` function and assign it's *return value* to the `onclick` attribute. Probably not what you want. Try removing the `()` after the function name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of:

```
document.getElementById('button_click').setAttribute('onClick', makeAreaEditable());
```

you need to do this:

```
editbutton.onclick = makeAreaEditable;
```

the function's name goes without brackets unless you want to execute it

instead of obtaining the element from the DOM using `document.getElementById('button_click')`
you can use the `editbutton` variable already created. this object is the DOM element you are looking for

SIDE NOTE:
the standard way to do it is to add the `onclick` property before appending the element

Comment: I am stuck again... how can i get in my makeareaeditable function the value of the li element.... text assigned to it.. i tried something like this : `code`var makeAreaEditable = function(){

 var textElement = document.getElementById('list').value;
 

 alert(textElement);

};
`code`

Comment: document.getElementById("list").nodeValue =)

Comment: make sure that the id of the li is getting set cross browser. another option is li.id = "list"; (instead of using setAttribute)

Comment: that returns me a null value

Comment: you may want to check if you are setting a value to the li in the code above (maybe you want the textnode's value? that's another node). remember you can browse the DOM childs using node.childNodes[i] being i the child index in the tree. firstChild can also by handy

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22765/discussion-between-paul-harbuz-and-canolucas)